# How to pass output path to webpack as parameter using npm?

Tags: angularjs, npm, webpack

I have a Angular application that uses Webpack as module bundler. In my package.json, I have the following scripts:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "webpack",
  "start-in-war": "??????"
}
```

Also, this is the output portion of my webpack.config.js

```
output: {
    path: __dirname + "/dist/",
    filename: "app.js"
}
```

Since I also want this application to be packaged into a WAR file with my backend service, I need to pass that path field as parameter, so I will mantain both configurations: the default that is more development-friendly (I don't have to deploy the application anytime I make a client change) and the one I will ultimately use (that would be the "start-in-war" parameter).

How can I achieve that?

Note: The start-in-war script is not gonna be used just for production, also development.